# AndEngine sprite movement

Tags: animation, sprites, andengine

I want to ask that I have a player in my game. I may walk. I have a image which has five different frames for walk and two frames for standing position. I want to ask that how can I change the images on runtime depending on the player state? I have loaded the image in tiledtextureregion. Also player can walk in forward and backward direction as well. How to use the same image strip for walking back and forth? I am new to andengine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can flip the texture like so:
myTextureRegion.setFlippedHorizontal(true);

or by using the sprite

mySprite.setFlippedHorizontal(true); // set false to flip it back

Have you looked at AnimatedSprite class?
[AnimatedSpriteClass](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/entity/sprite/AnimatedSprite.java?r=2c546d6cd9fdd009a54692498c38f1669b03c3ee)

You could google for examples. It's in the API